# how can install plugins for play mp3 and wma file which play on browser

Tags: browser, plugins

I am new user of ubuntu and i am facing an problem when i use web page and play any online mp3 voice file while my voice file not play i show an error " plug in missing ", ... I try to install this plugins but i am not able to install this plugins.

This problem persist on both browser firefox and chrome , I required plugins for mp3 and wma format , Kindly give me easy command for this issue step by step I m waiting for your quick responce

Regards 
DeepakSharma Tech Support Engineer New Delhi INDIA

Comment: Try installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to download CODECS.

To install the proprietary CODECs type the following in a terrminal window.

**32 bit OS**

`sudo apt-get -y install gstreamer0.10-pitfdll gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse`

**64 bit OS**

`sudo apt-get -y install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse`

Once you have installed these CODECs you will be able to play nearly any audio/video format.

I would recommend you to install Ubuntu restricted extras from the Software center.
you can also install *Ubuntu restricted extras* through the terminal by typing

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`